# Generating regex, from hosts file using bash/sed/awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a hosts file which is in the following format:

```
# comments

(ipv4/ipv6 address) (multiple hostnames)
.
.
.
```

I need to convert them to an optimised regular expression using bash/sed/awk. For example, if we have the following in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 abc.example.com def.examples.com
127.0.0.1 ghi-example.com foobar.com
127.0.0.1 malwaredomain.com malware-domain.com
```

to be converted as:

```
(((abc|def)\.|ghi-)\.example\.com|foobar\.com|malware-?domain\.com)
```

It may be preferable to also have some intelligent conversion. For example, if we have lots of similar entries like:

```
127.0.0.1 ad-us.adserver.com ad-uk.adserver.com ad-fr.adserver.com ad-de.adserver.com
127.0.0.1 ad-ru.adserver.com ad-ca.adserver.com ad-se.adserver.com ad-be.adserver.com
...
```

They may be converted as `ad\..*\.adserver.com`, maybe even as `ad\..{2}\.adserver\.com`. Of course something like `ad-(us|uk|fr|de|ru|ca|se|be)\.adserver\.com` works, but I'd prefer to have a generic rule since there's the additional benifit of detecting servers that may be added later.

EDIT: Summarising, if I have I have a hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 atmdt.com foo.atmdt.com bar.admdt.com
127.0.0.1 anifkalood.ru boeing-job.com ilianorkin.ru humaniopa.ru
127.0.0.1 hillairusbomges.ru mgithessia.biz justintvfreefall.org
```

The output will be a regex which covers all the servers above:

```
((((foo|bar)\.?atmdt|boeing-job)\.com)|(anifkalood|hillairusbomges|ilianorkin|humaniopa)\.ru|mgithessia\.biz|justintvfreefall\.org)
```

How can I acheive this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Perl module http://search.cpan.org/~manu/Net-IP-1.26/IP.pm might be of interest

Comment: The problem is in defining the limits of what should match/should not match.  After all `.*` would meet your requirements for a general rule, since it will match any entry! (and you could consider that optimised)

Comment: An implementation of this that looked like what you wanted (optimizing) would typically be done by building a tree. Bash (prior to the unreleased 4.3, which adds namerefs from ksh) doesn't support pointers or references, which are necessary for trees, so the facilities necessary for a sane and reasonable implementation are not present. Ignoring the shortest-possible condition, you could simply convert the `.` instances (or, ideally, any characters not explicitly whitelisted as safe) to `[.]`, add a `(` and `)` at the beginning and end and separate by `|`, but, well, that's not so interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to be looking for a regex generator. Here are some :

- [Regexp::List - builds regular expressions out of a list of words](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.15/lib/Regexp/List.pm) (Perl) - choosed by questionner/@user2064000
- [Automatic Generation of Regular Expressions from Examples](http://regex.inginf.units.it/) (Java/Javascript syntax)
- [JavaScript Regex Generator (beta)](http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php) (Javascript syntax)
- [knowing is obsolete :: regular expression generator](http://txt2re.com/) (not sure: perl php python java javascript coldfusion c c++ ruby vb vbscript j# c# c++.net vb.net)
- [Re-Gen - a Regex Generator](https://github.com/lahwran/regex_generator) (python syntax)

I would recommend the Genetic approach, but not sure about the optimization level they have.

Comment: Yes, I chose the regex generator, but I'll chose this one instead of the others you posted: http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.15/lib/Regexp/List.pm

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a Computer Science project than a simple programming question!

I don't think you'll find any straightforward bash/sed/awk instructions to do this. You want to create regular expressions programmatically, and sed/awk are typically more suited to *using* regexes. I guess you'd have to look into [approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and specifically, computing the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance) between two strings.